# iOS Label Text Based On Timed Function

Tags: ios, nsstring, nstimer, nsinteger

I've been trying to create a script that sets a timer and reduces a value by 33 each time it runs. In theory the timer should stop itself after 6 runs, but it keeps going and reaches negative values. Is there a reason for this?

```
-(void)checkValue:(NSTimer *)myTimer{

    if(pplint > 0){
        pplint = pplint-33;
        NSString *ppllefttext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pplint];
        peopleleft.text = ppllefttext;
        NSLog(@"Reduced Timer");   
    }
    if(pplint < 0){
        NSLog(@"Stop Timer");
        [myTimer invalidate];
    }
}


- (IBAction)gotocongrats{
    pplint = 198;
    NSString *ppllefttext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pplint];
    peopleleft.text = ppllefttext;
    NSTimer * myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(checkValue:)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
    NSLog(@"Started Timer");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took you code and edited it a bit and it works just fine for me.

```
-(void)checkValue:(NSTimer *)myTimer{

if(pplint > 0){
    pplint = pplint-33;

    NSLog(@"%i",pplint);
    NSLog(@"Reduced Timer");   
}
if(pplint <= 0){
    NSLog(@"Stop Timer");
    [myTimer invalidate];
    }
}

- (IBAction)gotocongrats{
pplint = 198;


NSTimer * myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(checkValue:)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
NSLog(@"Started Timer");
}
```

Comment: I tried the code out and the timer reaches negative values. What code did you use in your .h file?
All I have is:
`
    //thankyoupage
    IBOutlet UILabel *peopleleft;
    IBOutlet NSInteger *pplint;
`

Comment: Above my code I just have int pplint. I have an unedited .h I really think you should just use an int and NSInteger can't be an IBOutlet! I'm not sure you can have a * at a NSInteger. Why don't you try using a regular int?